# Story about Nazi dwarves inhabiting an old castle (in Ireland?)

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a novel by an English speaking author which is about — as the headline mentions — nazi dwarves that owe, if I remember correctly, their condition to genetic engineering and live in an old castle. It's pure pulp fiction, of course, but I don't remember much more about it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've just found the novel: It's *[The Little People](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13479933-the-little-people)* by John Christopher.

[image: Book Cover - The Little People]

> They speak German. They carry whips. And they are connected in some mysterious way with Nazi experiments carried out in the charming old Irish castle during World War II.
>
> When members of the vacation party are found missing from their beds, and when pleading cries ring through the halls of great house, terror grips hearts and minds, and the vacationers are brought face to face with the unknown...

Comment: I...just...but.. I can't.  This is too strange to be true.

Comment: Awesome! That made my day

Comment: There is a review at https://www.tor.com/2014/05/30/summer-of-sleaze-the-little-people/ with the charming details. They're called "Gestapochauns" and "These are Jewish psychic Nazi leprechauns who enjoy S&M, are covered with scars from pleasure/pain sessions with their creator, were trained as sex slaves for full-sized human men, and are actually stunted fetuses taken from Jewish concentration camp victims. And one of them is named Adolph."

Comment: I could have gone the rest of my life without seeing this. Now my life is forever tainted by the knowledge that this exists. Now if you will excuse me, there is a bottle of bleach and a funnel calling me...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - How could *anyone* have thought that was a good idea? It’s worse than *Hitlar* (Nazi Pakistani gangsters) or *Reign of the Gargoyles* (Nazi gargoyles).